# Magento Multi Site 404 issue with New Domain

Tags: php, magento

I have tried to Setup new Domain with `Magento Multisite`

I have created modification in `.htaccees`, and/or admin side also I have created store/website and View also I have created the root category

but it is showing  `404 not found` Error Page

while I am try to access http://kutchibandhani.com/ any solution for this

my .htaccess code is as follows

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.kutchibandhani\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=bandhani
SetEnvIf Host www\.kutchibandhani\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=bandhani
SetEnvIf Host ^kutchibandhani\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=bandhani
SetEnvIf Host ^kutchibandhani\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=bandhani
```

Comment: You're seeing magentos error page so something is working. Have you created a cms "home" page for the new domain?

Comment: in your index.php check what values are coming for $mageRunCode, $mageRunType

Answer (score 5):

The [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup) describes how to use Multiple websites in Magento. For .htaccess a possible solution is

```
SetEnvIf Host .*site.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=example
SetEnvIf Host .*site.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website # 'website' or 'store'
```

replace the type 'MAGE_RUN_TYPE=bandhani' with the 'MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website' or 'MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store' in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

1.MAGE_RUN_TYPE=  should be website or store .

2.MAGE_RUN_CODE =  "base" or some value  e.g "german"

in your index.php for store you want to check echo these values and check are they proper or not.